# jade compilation with gulp : TypeError

Tags: node.js, gulp, pug

I want to compile this `.jade` file using gulp. but i am getting some errors. with a gulp task i am compiling a batch of `.jade` files , files with out a variable compiles just fine, the file bellow where the compilation gets stuck

```
extends layout

block header
    meta(content=entry.Title, itemprop="name")
    block genre
    meta(content="/book/#{entry.authurl}/#{entry.titleurl}", itemprop="url")
    .row.text-center
        if (entry.Fields.length !== 0)
            h2.col-xs-12.col-md-12
                each field, index in entry.Fields
                    if (index === 0)
                        = field
                    else
                        = " >> " + field
        if (entry.Subfields.length !== 0)
            h3.col-xs-12.col-md-12
                each subfield, index in entry.Subfields
                    if (index === 0)
                        = subfield
                    else
                        = " >> " + subfield
block content
    input(id="bookid",value="#{entry._id}",type="hidden")
    section.row
        h1.col-xs-12.col-md-12= entry.Title
        dl.col-xs-12.col-md-8.dl-horizontal
            dt
            dd.text-right
                span.stars <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                span.library <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span> <img src="/booklist/bibtex_icon_small.png" class="get-bibtex" alt="Get BibTeX!">
            each val, index in entry.attrs
                dt= index
                if (index == "Author")
                    dd(id=index) <a href="/author/#{entry.authurl}">#{val}</a>
                else if (index == "Authors")
                    dd(id=index)
                        each auth, ind in entry.attrs.Authors
                            if (ind === 0)
                                <a href="/author/#{entry.authurls[ind]}">#{auth}</a>
                            else
                                | , <a href="/author/#{entry.authurls[ind]}">#{auth}</a>
                else
                    dd(id=index)= val
            block voteon
        aside.col-xs-12.col-md-4#ref
            block cataside
            h4
                strong Appears on:
            if (typeof(Lists) === "undefined")
                | An error occurred.
            else
                ul.list-unstyled
                    each list in Lists
                        li
                            a(href="/list/" + list.listurl)= list.Title
                if (Lists.length > 9)
                    p
                        a(href="/lists?" + entry.Title) All lists
    .row
        aside.col-xs-12.col-md-4.small
            strong Associated Links
            ul.list-unstyled
                each link in entry.Links
                    li= link
                button.newlink Add a link
        .col-xs-12.col-md-8
            p Write a Review
            each review in entry.Reviews
                h5= review.title
                article= review.body
```

when i execute gulp command

this error log shows up:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: /Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/views/entry.jade:4
    2|
    3| block header
  > 4|     meta(content=entry.Title, itemprop="name")
    5|     block genre
    6|     meta(content="/book/#{entry.authurl}/#{entry.titleurl}", itemprop="url")
    7|     .row.text-center

Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined
  at eval (<anonymous>:228:47)
  at eval (<anonymous>:994:22)
  at res (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:219:38)
  at DestroyableTransform.CompileJade [as _transform] (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp-jade/index.js:34:50)
  at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp-jade/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:159:10)
  at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp-jade/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:147:83)
  at doWrite (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp-jade/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:313:64)
  at writeOrBuffer (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp-jade/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:302:5)
  at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp-jade/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:241:11)
  at write (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
  at flow (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
  at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
  at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
  at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
  at emitReadable_ (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
  at emitReadable (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
  at readableAddChunk (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:187:9)
  at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:149:10)
  at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:145:32)
  at afterTransform (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:101:12)
  at TransformState.afterTransform (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:79:12)
  at DestroyableTransform.noop [as _transform] (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/through2.js:26:3)
  at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
  at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
  at doWrite (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
  at writeOrBuffer (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
  at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
  at write (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
  at flow (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
  at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
  at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
  at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
  at emitReadable_ (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
  at emitReadable (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
  at readableAddChunk (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:187:9)
  at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:149:10)
  at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:145:32)
  at afterTransform (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:101:12)
  at TransformState.afterTransform (/Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:79:12)
  at /Users/Orion/NodeWorks/WebDev/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/getContents/bufferFile.js:12:5
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (evalmachine.<anonymous>:380:3)
```

i am guessing this is related to variables,how can i make it work ?

Comment: Have you passed `entry` to your template?

Comment: this is the gulp task : 

gulp.task('gulpjade', function() {
    return gulp.src('views/*.jade')
        .pipe(gulpjade()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('templates'));
        
});

Comment: Yes I understand that. You don't have variable `entry` in your templates, because of that you getting this error. Can you post whole `jade` task?

Comment: what do you mean by whole jade task? did you mean whole gruntfile.js? that is consist of all grunt.task ?

Comment: No, just the part which is responsible for jade rendering, `gulp.task("gulpjade") ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109895/discussion-between-shafayat-alam-and-t1m0n).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't pass your `entry` variable to your jade templates. If you want to use data in `jade` files you need to pass it in your `gulp` task like this:

### Example of jade task with data

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),        
    jade = require('gulp-jade');

gulp.task('jade', function () {
    gulp.src('jade/index.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            // Pass data to templates
            data: {
                entry: {
                    Title: 'My page title',
                    authurl: '/some/url/' //... and so on
                }
            }
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('html/'))
});
```

### index.jade

```
h1= entry.Title
p Url is #{entry.authurl}
```

Comment: thanks. but this is for a single variable , what if i have to send a large number of data from node back end ? and how do i assign 'My page title' to Title(not some fixed value)?

Comment: @ShafayatAlam if your are using server rendering then you dont need any gulp jade tasks. Just pass data in `node.js` app. It all depends on your back end environment, e.g. example with express.js - http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: well, thanks.yes it works without gulp compilation. but isnt there any benefits of pre-compiling  with gulp? doesnt it respond faster if pre-compiled?